# Have error with memcache

Tags: php, yii, memcached, php-7, libmemcached

I am trying to get someone else's php and yii framework project working.  I get this error trying to run one of their files:

```
Error: Call to undefined function memcache_get() in /var/yaamp/web/yaamp/core/functions/memcache.php:15
```

That particular section of code looks like this:

```
    public function get($key)
{
    return memcache_get($this->memcache, $key);
}
```

Your initial response may be that memcache isn't installed or not working correctly.  But it is working.  In my phpinfo() I see a standard entry for memcache.  I also created a short php file pasted here that works just fine:

```
$mem_var = new Memcached();
$mem_var->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
$response = $mem_var->get("Bilbo");
if ($response) {
  echo $response;
  $mem_var->set("Bilbo", "Sent from memcache") or die("Dead");
} else {
  echo "Line 9";
  $mem_var->set("Bilbo", "Sent from memcache Line 10") or die("Dead");
}
```

I am new to memcache and not sure how to debug or fix this.  This is ubuntu 16.03, php7 and lighttpd server Any ideas?

Comment: you need to install **Memcache** not **Memcach`ed`**. The working script is for Memcached and that's why it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the difference between memcache and memcached? They are not the same, and if your script with `new Memcached` is working, but the one with `memcache_get` is not, then you have installed memcached, but not memcache

Comment: That was it!  I did sudo apt-get install php-memcache and I didn't get the error anymore.  Just for future visitors, I did not uninstall memcached.  And I restarted php7.0-fpm.service and lighttpd.service.  Thanks!